# Writing on MSB and on LSB of an unsigned Char

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have an unsigned char and i want to write `0x06` on the four most significant, and i want to write `0x04` on its 4 least significant bits.
So the Char representation should be like `0110 0010`

Can some can guide me how i can do this in C?

Comment: Just `c = 0x64;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = (0x06 << 4) | 0x04;
```

Because:

```
0x04    = 0000 0100
0x06    = 0000 0110

0x06<<4 = 0110 0000
or op:  = 0110 0100
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift values into the right position with the bitwise shift operators, and combine with bitwise *or*.

```
unsigned char c = (0x6 << 4) | 0x4;
```

To reverse the process and extract bitfields, you can use bitwise *and* with a mask containing just the bits you're interested in:

```
unsigned char lo4 = c & 0xf;
unsigned char hi4 = c >> 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure there are eight bits per `unsigned char`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#if CHAR_BIT != 8
    #error "This code does not support character sizes other than 8 bits."
#endif
```

Now, suppose you already have an `unsigned char` defined with:

```
unsigned char x;
```

Then, if you want to completely set an `unsigned char` to have 6 in the high four bits and 4 in the low four bits, use:

```
x = 0x64;
```

If you want to see the high bits to `a` and the low bits to `b`, then use:

```
// Shift a to high four bits and combine with b.
x = a << 4 | b;
```

If you want to set the high bits to `a` and leave the low bits unchanged, use:

```
// Shift a to high four bits, extract low four bits of x, and combine.
x = a << 4 | x & 0xf;
```

If you want to set the low bits to `b` and leave the high bits unchanged, use:

```
// Extract high four bits of x and combine with b.
x = x & 0xf0 | b;
```

The above presumes that `a` and `b` contain only four-bit values. If they might have other bits set, use `(a & 0xf)` and `(b & 0xf)` in place of `a` and `b` above, respectively.